# How do I scaling MODIS NDVI data in GEE?

Tags: maps, google-earth-engine

I want to download longterm series NDVI data, when I remove the cloud, I try to scaling NDVI to [-1,1], but it didn't work. Can you help me to solve this problem? The following is my code, roi is my research area.

```
//Batch download function
function exportImage(image, roi, fileName) {  
    Export.image.toDrive({  
       image: image,  
       description: "Drive-image-"+fileName,  
       fileNamePrefix: fileName+'_NDVI',  
       folder: "MODIS_NDVI",  
       scale: 250,  //resolution
       region: roi,  //studyarea
       maxPixels: 1e13,  //set as default
       crs: "EPSG:4326"  //set projection
   });  
 }
 
// Import MODIS data
var data = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13Q1").filterDate("2000-1-1", "2010-12-31")
            
Map.centerObject(roi, 4);  

//Preprocessing the data: create a function to apply the QA Bitmask, and output the cleaned(pixe with good quality only) VI data 
//Use quality control funciton to create a mask to mask out cloudy pixels in an input image based on the values in a band called 'SummaryQA'.
var modisqa_mask = function maskclouds(image) {
  //select the 'SummaryQA' band from the input image
  //this band contain quality assessment information
  var qa = image.select('SummaryQA');
  // Define a bitmask for the first condition (Mask1)
  var Mask1 = 1 << 0;  
  // Apply the bitmask and check if the corresponding bit is unset (equal to 0)
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(Mask1).eq(0);
  
  // Define a bitmask for the second condition (Mask2)
  var Mask2 = 1 << 1;
  var Mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(Mask2).eq(0);
  // Combine the masks from both conditions using the 'and' operator
  //the pixel must satisfy both conditions to pass the overall mask
  mask = mask.and(Mask);
  // Update the image mask based on the combined mask
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

//select NDVI data based on roi and prefered time range
//ImageCollection.filterBounds(geometry)//Returns the filtered collection.
//var data_selected = data.filterBounds(roi) 
            //.filterDate("2000-1-1", "2010-12-31")
            //.select('NDVI') //select band
//print("data_selected", data_selected); //check image numbers
//Check the long-term trend of monthly NDVI from 2000 to 2010 with chart
//print(ui.Chart.image.series(data_selected, roi, ee.Reducer.mean(), 250))


//images only with good pixel
//var nocloud_data = data_selected.map(modisqa_mask);
//print(nocloud_data);

var trueColor143 =
    data.select('NDVI');
var trueColor143Vis = {
  min: -1,
  max: 1,
};

var nocloud = data.map(modisqa_mask)
                    .select('NDVI');
print(ui.Chart.image.series(nocloud, roi, ee.Reducer.mean(), 250))
print(nocloud)
print(nocloud.projection) 

// Define the reprojection function
var pro = function(image){
  // Reproject the image to EPSG:4326
  var img = image.reproject({
    crs: 'EPSG:4326',  // Target projection
    scale: 250  // Target scale
  });
  
  return img;
};

// Apply the reprojection function to each image in the ImageCollection
var ndi_pro = nocloud.map(pro);

// Print the modified ImageCollection
print(ndi_pro);

var multiply = function(image){ 
 // multply image  
 var img = image.multiply(0.0001);  
 return img.set('system:time_start',image.get('system:time_start')) ;
 };
var ndvi = ndi_pro.map(multiply);


// Create a time series chart
var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: ndvi,
  region: roi,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 250, // Resolution
});
```

when I run this code, the output isn't scaling to [-1,1], I was so confused. And may I ask do you think my steps to remove the cloud is correct or not?